# Innertext Ignore All Words in Front of &nbsp;

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, innertext

I am scraping the innertext of a table, but this column has tooltip which the HTMLAgilityPack function scrape the tooltip and exact data altogether.

Suppose I just want their names and I do not need all the words before `&nbsp;` including `&nbsp;` itself. May I know how can I achieve this?

```
Antony Jenkins held the position of CEO at Barclays at the time of this trade.&nbsp;Antony Jenkins
Frits Van Paasschen held the position of Non-Executive Director at Barclays at the time of this trade.&nbsp;Frits Van Paasschen
David A Walker held the position of Non-Executive Chairman at Barclays at the time of this trade.&nbsp;David A Walker
```

I tried to use `cols6[j].InnerText.Replace ("&nbsp;", "")` but it obviously won't remove those words in front of it except `&nbsp;` itself.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

As requested by Alexei, HTML table would be as below:

```
<tr><th>Trade Date</th><th>Action</th><th>Notifier</th><th>Price</th><th>Currency</th><th>Amount</th><th>Holding</th></tr>
<tr class="on"><td>13-Dec-13</td><td>Scrip Dividend</td><td><div class="TradesInfo"><img onmouseover="$('#TradePopD0').css('visibility', 'visible');" onmouseout="$('#TradePopD0').css('visibility', 'hidden');" src="http://static.lse.co.uk/images/icons/info.png" width="14" height="14" align="left" alt="Trade Notifier Information for Barclays"><div class="TradesPop" id="TradePopD0">Antony Jenkins held the position of CEO at Barclays at the time of this trade.</div></div>&nbsp;Antony Jenkins</td><td>0</td><td></td><td>71</td><td>0</td></tr>
```

Everything was okay, just the column with tooltip.

Comment: Can you show HTML? It may be much easier to grab text of specific elements instead of trying to pars combined innerText...

Comment: Hi Alexei, I've updated my question to include the HTML snippet. :) Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Clearly if you get innerText from particular `div` elements you'll not need to do ridiculous string splitting.  Something around `div/div[2]`...

Comment: Hi Alexei, is there a way to ignore `div` in this line `HtmlNodeCollection cols3 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[3]");`? The name is in `<td>`, not in `<div>` so basically what I want is to ignore fully the data in the two `<div></div>`.

Comment: Hi Alexei, I tried this and it works. `HtmlNodeCollection cols3 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[3]/text()");` :)

Comment: Okay, thank you for your hints and advice, I will be sure to inspect the elements before going down to string splitting. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a combination of String.Substring and String.IndexOf.

As a very crude example..

```
private static string RemoveStringStart(string text)
{
    var splitAt = "&nbsp;";
    if (text.Contains(splitAt))
    {
        text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(splitAt) + splitAt.Length);
    }

    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expression to ignore everything till the & nbsp;

Have a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

In Jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/qG4Px/2/

In C#:

```
string test = "Some text &nbsp; more text";
test.Remove(0,test.IndexOf("&nbsp")+6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, thanks to all for giving me hints :D

I tried this and it works. This will not take any `<div></div>` in the `<td></td>` into account, instead, it will only take the "text" inside the `<td></td>`

```
HtmlNodeCollection cols3 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[3]/text()");
```

:)